# Failed to establish a backside connection

Tags: wcf

When my ASP.NET WCF service calls another ASP.NET WCF service the following is returned:

> Failed to establish a backside connection
>   Server stack trace:
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      at ServiceNameSpace.Service.ServiceType.getStatus(getStatusRequest request)

Any ideas?

Update 10:12 AM - After looking at this for a while: my guess is the other service doesn't like some of the data we pass to it. I think it's not validating inputs and then throws an exception on a null reference or perhaps a DB query.

PS. Names of components in the last stack trace line changed for security\privacy reasons.

PS. I tried to do a search. I pasted my title into the search box and then clicked on search to the left of the input box. Nothing happened.

Comment: This likely is an issue with the service you are calling. I typically see "Failed to establish a backside connection" errors when calling IBM Datapower.

Answer (score 1):

I would search the source code of the calling wcf service for the term *Failed to establish a backside connection*.

I am fairly certain there is no built-in exception message in the WCF stack with that exact terminology.

Once you have found the code which throws the exception then you will be step closer to solving the problem ;)